# Can't Find observableCollection.cs Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I was debugging c# code in Visual Studio 2013 and stepped into the line shown in the figure below
[image]

Then I get this error:
[image]

I don't know where it is getting the initial folder. I don't have a drive f. Not even a mapped network drive. I changed the code to use a List instead of a collection. Same results. This is in the master branch. I opened it this morning to create a branch and add a feature. So I was stepping through the code to find the best place to begin when the error occurred. I have cleaned and rebuilt the project. I have checked my references. But I don't know where to look for the solution. Hopefully one of you can help me. This particular piece of code has been in production for some time. You can also see that the line is no big deal. Just create a new collection.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: observableCollection.cs is part of .Net... If you don't have the .Net source you probably won't find it... why do you have to step into it?

Comment: Not "Step into it" just F11 execute next line. What would have happened to the .Net source? Where did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step *over* it (F10) or check the `Enable Just My Code` option under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.

`ObservableCollection<T>` is a class that is part of the .NET Framework so you shouldn't have to worry about debugging the code in this class. If you do want to debug it for some reason, you should enable .NET Framework source debugging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Yeah. I don't want to debug ObservableCollection. I just want to execute that line. You know just hit F11 each time and move on through the code like every day. But you fixed the problem. I don't know how that got unchecked. Reading your comment and Amitai's comment I see what was happening. Execution was trying to enter into the observablecollection class to step though it. Understanding strikes!